# Error installing Microsoft SQL Server MGMT Studio 2016

Tags: ssms

I've tried to install Microsoft SQL Server MGMT Studio but I have the following error:

> Fatal error during installation (0x80070643)
>
> Setup is missing an installation prerequisite: - Microsoft System CLR Types for SQL Server 2016 RC3.

I've searched but not found this requirement.

Comment: If you want to try having different CTP versions of the product. Uninstall the newer version of SQLCLRTypes, install SSMS. If you encounter issues with the older version SQLCLRTypes(You shouldn't, but it is possible if API's changed), reinstall the newer version from setup and you will be OK. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/edb5c2a4-ea69-4440-b2a2-0d1f156b8263/clr-types-for-sql-server-2016-install-error?forum=SQLServer2016Preview

Comment: work like a charm!! thanks

Answer (score 1):

try with [this](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52676) Feature Pack. Microsoft SQL Server 2016 Feature Pack is a collection of stand-alone packages which provide additional value for Microsoft SQL Server.

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

Execute with admin privileges.

1. Right click in the installer.
2. Select and click in **Run as administrator**.

The first time, i run the installer with double click, and haves this error **(0x80070643)**, later.. the second time, i try run this with admin privileges and its completed the installation without problems.

***NOTE:*** Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Release 17.